# MongoDB client cannot be accessed

Tags: php, mongodb

I installed MongoDB on Ubuntu server, its running fine when accessed through RoboMongo and can be accessed from outside but when I run the same code on ubuntu serer its not working and giving error : 503 (Service temporarily unavailable)

Here's the code :

```
    <?php
         echo "Hello";
 if($connect = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");)
  {
         echo "Connection to database successfully";
         echo "<br>";
  } 
    else
    {
          echo "Failed";
       }
          $DataBase = $connect->dbname;
              echo "Database mydb selected";
        echo "<br>";

               $collection = $DataBase->collectionname;
               echo "Collection selected succsessfully";
                echo "<br>";
                 ?>
```

"Hello" is getting printed but anything else is not coming.
Help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` with your text editor. Go to the end of the file and try to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is, mongo-php extension not installed.